# Add a new column to multiple .csv and populate with filename

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new in python and I have a folder with 15 excel files  and I am trying to rename a specific column in each file to a standard name, for instance I have a columns named "name, and server" on different files but they entail of the same information so I need to rename them to a standard name like " server name" and I don't know how to start

Comment: You many use pandas library for this. You may loop over the files and use "read_excel" method to make it into dataframe. Later you may rename it in the code of yours.

Comment: Excel files aren't csv files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the position of the columns are the same across all excel file, you can iterate all the 15 excel files, locate the position of the column and replace the text directly.

Alternatively, you can iterate all the files via read_xls (or read_csv depending on your context), reading them as dataframe and replace the necessary column name, and overwrite the file. Below is a reference syntax for your reference.

df.rename(columns={ df.columns[1]: "your value" }, inplace = True)

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity's sake, suppose your current folder has a folder named `folder` where all those 15 excel files with the following names `file_1.xlsx, file_2.xlsx, ......, file_15.xlsx` reside.

Now you can use `glob` to discover filepath and `pandas` to read those paths. Install pandas as `pip install pandas xlrd`.

```py
from glob import glob
import pandas as pd

# discover the path of all the xlsx files
filenames = glob('folder/*.xlsx')
```

Now let's say you want to rename the column 'name, and server' to 'nameserver'

```py
for filename in filenames:
    # read each of the file
    df = pd.read_excel(filename)

    # rename the column name
    df = df.rename(columns={'name, and server': 'nameserver'})

    # save the renamed files as csv
    df.to_csv(filename.split('.')[-2] + '.csv')
```

Comment: Hello the code runs and produces csv files but with the same names from the excell files, so it does not rename them

Comment: Updated my answer to fix the bug. I forgot to assign the same variable after mutating the column name. Could you please try now?

Comment: is there a simple way to now add a column on each csv with the csv file names?

Comment: You can load the csv files just like you did the excel files and do this `df[csvfilename] = [ ]`. This will add an empty column to the csv data frame that has the same name as the filename.

Comment: okay I want the column name to be 'Filename' and the data in the column to be the name of the file for instance let's say the name of the csv is one.csv so I wanna have  a column named File name that contains 'one' in every row but I am looking for a way to do automatically do for all the csv's  in a specific folder